# How to preview a coldfusion page in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, coldfusion-9, cfeclipse

I have cf installed in ~/Sites and my Eclipse projects are stored into ~/Documents/workspace

How do I preview a page that I've written in Eclipse (I'm using CFEclipse plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making a new workspace for coldfusion in ~/Sites/workspace and it works.